# Create key value array with object in Ramda

Tags: parsing, ramda.js, react-gql

I am working with a data structure like this

```
const res = {
                "Id": "7ba",
                "Group": {
                    "Id": "ALL",
                    "Strategy": {
                        "name": "random",
                        "Distribution": {
                            "Origin": 0.5,
                            "V1": 0.4
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Path": {
                    "affiliatePage": {
                        "types": [
                            {
                                "Name": "Origin",
                                "variables": {
                                    "returnUrl": ""
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "V1",
                                "variables": {
                                    "returnUrl": "asds"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
}
```

but i want the Path object to be like this

```
Path : [{key :"affiliatePage" , 
           types : [
                            {
                                "Name": "Origin",
                                "variables": {
                                    "returnUrl": ""
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "V1",
                                "variables": {
                                    "returnUrl": "asds"
                                }
                            }
                         ]
}]
```

and Distribution object to be like

```
Distribution : [{key : "Origin" , value: 0.5},{key : "V1" , value: 0.4}]
```

I tried the following thing but its of no help , don't know where i am going wrong

```
const mapper = (val) => { key: val , 
                   value:GroupData[val]}
const GroupData = R.path(['Group','Strategy','Distribution'])(res)
const PathParser =  R.ifElse(
    R.isNil(R.prop('Path')),
    R.always(null),
    R.applySpec({
      key: R.keysIn(R.prop('Path'))[0],
      types : R.valuesIn(R.prop('Path'))[0].types
    })
)

const GroupParser =  R.ifElse(
    R.isNil(R.prop('Group')),
    R.always(null),
    R.applySpec({
      Distribution : R.map(mapper, R.keysIn(R.path(['Group', 'Strategy', 'Distribution'])))
    })
)
 const transform = R.applySpec({
  Path: PathParser,
  Group: GroupParser
})
console.log(transform(res))
```

i am getting error as *First argument to _arity must be a non-negative integer no greater than ten.*
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

Because your transformations are not related, the best thing I can see is to write them as individual functions, one that would transform a `Distribution` node and one that would transform a `Path` node, then combine them into a single function, either by composing lens-based functions or using Ramda's [`evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve).

In either case the individual functions might look like this:

```js
const distFn = pipe (toPairs, map (zipObj (['key', 'value'])))
const pathFn = pipe (toPairs, map (([k, v]) => ({key: k, ...v})))
```

I'm sure that if we tried, we could make the latter point-free, but I don't see the, ahem, *point* of doing so.

The lens-based solution might look like this:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  over (lensPath (['Group', 'Strategy', 'Distribution']), distFn),
  over (lensPath (['Path']), pathFn)
)
```

```js
const distFn = pipe (toPairs, map (zipObj (['key', 'value'])))
const pathFn = pipe (toPairs, map (([k, v]) => ({key: k, ...v})))

const transform = pipe (
  over (lensPath (['Group', 'Strategy', 'Distribution']), distFn),
  over (lensPath (['Path']), pathFn)
) 

const res = {Id: "7ba", Group: {Id: "ALL", Strategy: {name: "random", Distribution: {Origin: 0.5, V1: 0.4}}}, Path: {affiliatePage: {types: [{Name: "Origin", variables: {returnUrl: ""}}, {Name: "V1", variables: {returnUrl: "asds"}}]}}}

console .log(transform (res))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, toPairs, map, zipObj, over, lensPath} = R          </script>
```

The `evolve` solutions could look like this:

```js
const transform = evolve ({
  Group: {Strategy: {Distribution: distFn}},
  Path: pathFn
})
```

```js
const distFn = pipe (toPairs, map (zipObj (['key', 'value'])))
const pathFn = pipe (toPairs, map (([k, v]) => ({key: k, ...v})))

const transform = evolve ({
  Group: {Strategy: {Distribution: distFn}},
  Path: pathFn
})

const res = {Id: "7ba", Group: {Id: "ALL", Strategy: {name: "random", Distribution: {Origin: 0.5, V1: 0.4}}}, Path: {affiliatePage: {types: [{Name: "Origin", variables: {returnUrl: ""}}, {Name: "V1", variables: {returnUrl: "asds"}}]}}}

console .log(transform (res))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, toPairs, map, zipObj, evolve} = R                  </script>
```

In either case, if `distFn` and `pathFn` aren't used elsewhere, it would do no harm to fold them into the main function... except that it might become less readable and might be more difficult to write test cases for.

Between the two, it's hard to decide.  The `lens` solution uses more common functional programming idioms.  But the `evolve` one is somewhat more explicit and might be slightly more performant (at an untested guess.)

Answer (score 2):

this could help perhaps:

```js
const evolve = (path, evolver) => R.over(
  R.lensPath(path),
  R.pipe(R.toPairs, R.map(evolver)),
);

const ev = R.pipe(
  evolve(
    ['Path'],
    ([key, value]) => R.mergeRight({ key }, value),
  ),
  evolve(
    ['Group', 'Strategy', 'Distribution'],
    ([key, value]) => ({ key, value }),
  ),
);


// ======

const raw = {
  "Id": "7ba",
  "Group": {
    "Id": "ALL",
    "Strategy": {
      "name": "random",
      "Distribution": {
        "Origin": 0.5,
        "V1": 0.4
      }
    }
  },
  "Path": {
    "affiliatePage": {
      "types": [
        {
          "Name": "Origin",
          "variables": {
            "returnUrl": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "Name": "V1",
          "variables": {
            "returnUrl": "asds"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

console.log(
  ev(raw),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, and a nice function, but I wouldn't, when mixing with Ramda, reuse the name `evolve`.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I haven't thought the name throught! Naming is always hard, but definitely `evolve` looks very misleading here!